# Compare 2 big CSV files and output to another file

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd, compare, diff

I want to compare 2 big CSV files (about 120 Mb) with over 200 columns.
This is the command that I use:

FC file1.txt file2.txt >difference.csv

The difference is file2.txt has 3 more rows than file1.txt.
But in difference.csv instead of 3 rows, each row is split into multiple rows (almost like there is a line break).

The 3 rows are the "1111", "222" and "333" rows.

The file looks like this in Notepad:
[image]

The file looks like this in Excel:
[image]

How can I fix this ?
Also, how can I create the file without the comment "Comparing files file1.txt and file2.TXT
***** file1.txt
***** file2.TXT" and without the "******" at the end of the file ?

Edited the question:
Using "findstr" gives an error "search string too long"

findstr /v /g:"file1.txt" "file2.txt" >> "diffFindStr.csv"

Using this powershell command used up all the RAM on my machine and never finished:

```
$Group = import-csv -path "c:\myfolder\file1.txt" 
$OU = import-csv -path "c:\myfolder\file2.txt" 
Compare-Object $Group $OU -property UniqueNameInFile -IncludeEqual | where-object {$_.SideIndicator -eq "=>"} | Export-csv DifferencePS.csv –NoTypeInformation
```

Is there another way to compare 2 large files using CMD or Powershell or anything else ?

Thank you.

Comment: Looks like `fc` inserts a line-break in its output after every 127 characters, so you cannot change that. To prevent the extra lines from being output you could filter them out by `findstr` like this: `fc "file1.txt" "file2.txt" | findstr /V /L /B /C:"Comparing files " /C:"*****" > "difference.csv"`

Comment: Thank you. The extra lines are now gone.
Is there a way to replace the line break with blank in the FC output ?

Comment: Removing line-breaks is not that easy in pure CMD/batch scripting. And you need to detect which line-breaks are intentional (so coming from the original files)...

Comment: Thank you. Good point.
Is there any other way to compare 2 large CSV files and output the difference to a 3rd file ?
Using "findstr" gives an error "search string too long"
findstr /v /g:"file1.txt" "file2.txt" >> "diffFindStr.csv"

Using this powershell command used up all the RAM on my machine and never finished:
$Group = import-csv -path "c:\myfolder\file1.txt"
$OU = import-csv -path "c:\myfolder\file2.txt"
Compare-Object $Group $OU -property UniqueNameInFile -IncludeEqual | where-object {$_.SideIndicator -eq "=>"} | Export-csv DifferencePS.csv –NoTypeInformation

Comment: Windows CMD is very limited in line lengths. Since you have huge files with many columns, I believe it is not possible at all, or at least the performance is very poor. So switching to PowerShell may be a good option. Unfortunately I cannot help you with that. You should [edit] the question, include your PowerShell attempt and add the [tag:powershell] tag, so somebody else might help..

Comment: I edited the question. Thank you.

Comment: I ended up using this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49179424/using-perl-to-compare-2-large-files

Comment: From the the comparisons you show the tables look pretty unstructured. Are these actually (CSV) tables with a column header etc. (is there a common column name?) or are these just text files? (as you apparently are only interested in text comparison solutions)...