# Using Perl to compare 2 large files

Tags: windows, perl, cmd, compare, diff

I am comparing 2 large CSV file using Perl that's called in a batch file. 
I put the result in a 3rd file.

Currently the file contains other information like headers, and other lines like this:

```
--- file1.txt   Wed Mar  7 14:57:10 2018
+++ file2.txt   Wed Mar  7 13:56:51 2018
@@ -85217,4 +85217,8 @@
```

How can the result file only contains the difference ?
Thank you.

This is my perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict; use warnings;
use Text::Diff;
my $diffs = diff 'file1.txt' => 'file2.txt';
print $diffs;
```

This is my batch file:

```
perl diffperl.pl > newperl.csv
```

Comment: By the way, Beyond Compare Pro (not free, but free trial) is a great compare tool, and it specifically has an excellent CSV-compare mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the unified format,

- The first two lines indicate the files being compared.
- Lines that start with "`@`" indicate location of the differences in the file.
- Lines that start with a "`-`" indicates a line that is only in the first file.
- Lines that start with a "`+`" indicates a line that is only in the second file.
- Lines that start with a space indicate a line that is in both files.
- The output may contain the line "`\ No newline at end of file`".
- Every line of in the difference will be newline-terminated, even if the lines of the input aren't.

Solution:

```
$diffs =~ s/^(?:[^\n]*+\n){2}//;
$diffs =~ s/^[\@ \\][^\n]*+\n//mg;
```

Note that adding `CONTEXT => 0` will reduce the number of lines to remove.

---

That said, there's not much point in using [Text::Diff](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text::Diff) if you want your own output format. You might as well use [Algorithm::Diff](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Algorithm::Diff) directly.

```
use Algorithm::Diff qw( traverse_sequences );

my $qfn1 = 'file1.txt';
my $qfn2 = 'file2.txt';

my @file1 = do { open(my $fh, '<', $qfn1) or die("Can't open \"$qfn1\": $!\n"); <$fh> };
my @file2 = do { open(my $fh, '<', $qfn2) or die("Can't open \"$qfn2\": $!\n"); <$fh> };

if (@lines1) { chomp($lines1[-1]); $lines1[-1] .= "\n"; }
if (@lines2) { chomp($lines2[-1]); $lines2[-1] .= "\n"; }

traverse_sequences(\@lines1, \@lines2, {
   DISCARD_A => sub { print("-", $lines1[$_[0]]); },
   DISCARD_B => sub { print("+", $lines2[$_[1]]); },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should look at the `STYLE` option in [the documentation for Text::Diff](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::Diff). It's possible that one of the built-in styles might be more to your liking. But if that's not the case you could write your own formatting package. It sounds to me like you would just need to supply a `hunk_header()` method that returns an empty string (as it's the hunk header lines that you don't like).

Comment: Thank you all. The solution from ikegami works !
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict; use warnings;

use Text::Diff;

my $diffs = diff 'file1.txt' => 'file2.txt';
$diffs =~ s/^(?:[^\n]*+\n){2}//;
$diffs =~ s/^(?:[\@ ][^\n]*+)?+\n//mg;

print $diffs;

Is it possible to include the header from file1.txt in newperl.csv ?
Thank you.

Comment: @faujong: Posting code in a comment really isn't very useful :-) If you have another question, please make a new post.